# simulating a button click impression

Tags: jquery, html, css, meteor

This meteor client code tries to give the impression that a button is being clicked. It uses the `onmousedown` event to apply a class to a `div` but it is not applying the class when checking the browser element tab.
What is wrong with it? Thanks

```
Template.footer.events({
  'click .footerItem': function(event) {
    //do some stuff here
  },
  'onmousedown .footerItem': function(event) {
    $(event.target).addClass('inset');
  },
  'onmouseup .footerItem': function(event) {
    $(event.target).removeClass('inset');
  }
});
```

```css
.inset {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 6px #999;
}

.footer-row {
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<template name="footer">
  <footer class="footer-row">
    {{#each footerButtons}}
    <div class="footerItem" data-action={{this.action}}>{{this.label}</div>
    {{/each}}
  </footer>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use :focus and :active css states. My advise is for visual stuff try to use JavaScript as little as possible.

> The :focus CSS pseudo-class is applied when an element has received focus, either from the user selecting it with the use of a keyboard or by activating with the mouse (e.g. a form input).
>
> The :active CSS pseudo-class matches when an element is being activated by the user. It allows the page to give a feedback that the activation has been detected by the browser.

CSS:

```
.footer-row {
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: white;
}

.footer-row:active,
.footer-row:focus {
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 6px #999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `"mousedown"` and `"mouseup"` instead of `"onmousedown"` and `"onmouseup"` respectively.